# HTML Pattern Input to Allow Only Specific Numbers

Tags: html, forms, input

I want the zip code part of my form, so only 5 numbers allowed, to reject anything that doesn't start with 46,52,53,54,60,61,62 using an html pattern

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you show the code that you have tried so far (i.e. the HTML with some regex in it).

Comment: @MikePoole Actually, you can do it with just HTML; see [the `pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#pattern).

Comment: I've tried [46|52|53|54|60|61|62]{5} I've tried /^(?=\d{5}$)(46|52|53|54|60|61|62)\d+/ and other variations but nothing works

Comment: Try this: `^(46|52|53|54|60|61|62)([0-9]{3})$`

Comment: Please [edit] you question with the variations you have tried.

Comment: @FeldcoDM please see the answer. The pattern can be used in `HTML` form `input` fields (built-in validation) or in Javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below pattern (starts with one of the specified numbers and then allow 3 digits):

`^(46|52|53|54|60|61|62)([0-9]{3})$`

Here is the running HTML sample. You may use this pattern in Javascript as well if you want to perform the validation yourself:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prescriptions</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="#">
        Country code: <input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="^(46|52|53|54|60|61|62)([0-9]{3})$"
            title="Enter five digit number starting with specific numbers">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

</body>
```